# How to upload a file and post multiple params by AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm learning how to using AFNetworking for iOS.I often use ASIHttprequest to upload a file and post multiple params at the same time before,it's simple using ASIHttprequest like this.

```
[request setPostValue:distanceLabel.text forKey:@"km"];
[request setPostValue:speedValue forKey:@"speed"];
[request setFile:filePath forKey:@"filedata"];
```

I learn a lot about AFNetworking,but I don't know how to do yet.Please show me the code.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try following code :-

I have used this code with an image. You can try with other file types as well.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(aDict[@"Image"], 0.5);

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:aStrURL parameters:aDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:myParamName fileName:@"photoNew.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
}];
[op start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the multi query values for one key.

If you use `NSDictionary` + `NSSet` you get query url without [] from `NSArray`.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil], @"myKey", nil];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/path" parameters:params];

NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                            name:@"files"
                        fileName:photoName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
```

Comment: Thanks! the code shows how to post multi values without a file. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking has great examples,
here how I use this stuff
1. create your client instance, which will serve the app every time it will need to connect to the server

file.h

```
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

@interface YourClient : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

+ (instancetype)sharedClient;
- (void)send_Image_POST_WS:(NSString *)ws_name image:(NSData*)imageData param:(NSDictionary *)param :(void (^)(NSDictionary *json, NSError *error, NSInteger status))block;
```

file.m

```
static NSString * const YouBaseURLString = @"http://blablabla";
@implementation YourClient


+ (instancetype)sharedClient {

    static YourClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[YourClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL YouBaseURLString]];
        _sharedClient.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

     });

    return _sharedClient;
}

// you can change the block according to the needs of its receiver

- (void)send_Image_POST_WS:(NSString *)ws_name image:(NSData*)imageData param:(NSDictionary*)param :(void (^)(NSDictionary *json, NSError *error, NSInteger status))block{

     // NSLog(@“WS: %@\nPARAMS: --> %@",ws_name,[param description]);

    [self POST:ws_name parameters:param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"imagedata" fileName:@"imagedata.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        if (block) {
           // NSLog(@"WS:%@\nRESPONSE : -> %@",ws_name,responseObject);
            block(responseObject,nil,operation.response.statusCode);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

         //NSLog(@"Response error text %@",operation.responseString);
       // you can display here alert
        if (block) {
            block(nil,error,operation.response.statusCode);
        }
    }];
 }
```

2. Class which  has to send an image for example

ProfileViewController.m

```
-(void)send_UploadImage:(UIImage *)image{

// here you can activate a spinner (use which one you want - of Apple or some open source)  
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"extension":@"png",
                             @“usr_id”:@“1”};// <<<—— this is an additional data the service on the server side will need, just example, replace with needed

    NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
// @"common/upload_image" replace with your path to the service on the server side, it will be added to the Base URL

    [[YourClient sharedClient] send_Image_POST_WS:@"common/upload_image" image:dataImage param:params :^(NSDictionary *json, NSError *error) {

        // hide spinner

        if (!error) {
        // read json, change UI here you are on the main thread    


        }else{
          // react accordingly main thread
        }
    }];
}
```